# Does REST for Google Tasks work?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest

I m trying to use the Google Task Queues in the Google App engine.

Particualrly I want to use the REST API to access the Pull queues from outside the App Engine. 
First I try to use the API explorer available here (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/rest/taskqueues/get) to execute some REST calls. However every call fails for unspecified reasons.

Have anyone used the API explorer successfully? Since the REST API is in experimental mode I m wondering whether it s not working properly

Comment: What is the error that is returned upon calling that REST resource? It is quite common that you'll end up with access denied error. Make sure you turn on Oauth 2.0 in API explorer and add your gmail user to queue.xml <acl>
        <user-email>user@email.com</user-email>
        </acl> . Just to finish for me it works fine then.